# Building package automatically assumes existence of a class

Tags: r

I have build my first R package and have the following issue: I have a function which is called `plot.fig` which should plot a project specific thing. Now when I build the package it automatically assumes, that figure is a S3 object:

```
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
plot:
  function(x, ...)
plot.fig:
  function(fig1,fig2)
```

How can I resolve this issue without renaming my function?

Comment: Not sure, but it seems like R assumes you wrote a `plot` method but you didn't intend to.  Have you tried changing the name of the function to something that does not start with `plot.`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to rename your function? That's just a really poor choice given how R does S3 dispatch.

Comment: Use an underscore instead of a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

First, this is a warning, not an error, so you are free to ignore it.  If this package is only for your own use then it does not really matter.  If you are sharing the package then you can tell those that you share with to ignore it.  The one barrier here is that CRAN will not publish it with the warning (not sure about github or others).

You could change your function to match the generic (make the first argument named "x") and create a function that creates 'fig' objects even if the function does not do anything useful (and do any needed registering in the NAMESPACE file).  This will make the dispatch system happy and stop the warning (but this is a kludge).

You could create a proper OO system that your function is a method in.

You can change your functions file name (even though you don't want to).  This is probably the cleanest.  If you just ignore the warning and later have a package (possibly 3rd party) loaded that creates objects of type 'fig' then your function may be called by S3 method dispatch even though it is not the appropriate plotting function.  The warning is steering you towards defensive programming to avoid this possible mistake.